# Web service working fine on browser but not from android code

Tags: android, web-services

I am trying to create login for my application. The given url works fine when i try it in web browser but web service is not working with the following code in android application. For testing purpose i have hard coded the url link.
I have already set internet permission in manifest.xml file.

```
String uri= "http://192.168.1.6:8080/Cloud/webresources/generic/login?user=ankita&pass=1234";
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        out.close();
        String responseString = out.toString();
        if(responseString.equals("success"))
        {
            System.out.println("Successful login");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayDetailsActivity.class);
            String message = "User id is: success";//+userid.toString();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Unsuccessful login");
        }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `"web service is not working"` is not really very helpful. Can you please specify exactly what error you are getting ?

Comment: I mean to say that i am not getting any response. Means no system.out.println statement works after calling url.

Comment: any error occurs or not.??

Comment: no errors are there. It is printing all println statements before url and none after url

Comment: @AnkitaJain response return string or jsonObject?

Comment: Just for safety - log the `statusLine` value, and the `responseString` value - make sure that they are set as you expect.

Comment: Problem is with this statement   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); I tried putting print statements and everything above this statement is printing.

Comment: Some time if you increase the socket connection timeout time for your http client request , it will resolve the issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ankita Have you add your code inside AsyncTask Thread ?

Comment: @Ankita Before making http request you need to put this code in Thread. In Android you can use AsyncTask. 
You can see sample code in link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667255/following-android-http-example-tutorial-issue-implementing-async-task-for-ne

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot... I was trying to solve this error for last 5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
 try {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String uri= "http://192.168.1.6:8080/Cloud/webresources/generic/login?"

        String request = uri + java.net.URLEncoder.encode("user=ankita&pass=1234", "UTF-8");

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(request);
        HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);
        HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();

        if (resEntityGet != null) {
            String response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
            Log.i("Search Response", response);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

have  you written both this lines in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
```

Comment: do i need to include any jar files for running web services on android in eclipse?

Comment: No jar files are required for webservices please check edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.6:8080/Cloud/webresources/generic/login");
    try {
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user","ankita"));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass","1234"));
      post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

      HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
      String line = "";
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

put appropriate permission in **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

Comment: I am not posting anything. Why should i use httppost instead of httpget?

Comment: you should post username and password and then you have to check in backend if it is store in database then send response ok otherwise send any message like "username and password not match" or anything else.

Comment: username and password already exists in database. I am just comparing them with what user have entered.So the string should return success or fail.

Comment: you can send username and password and compare?what is problem you are faceing.